# The normalization equals the disjoint union of the normalizations of the irreducible components

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, birational-geometry

I am trying to understand [0CDV](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CDV) from the Stacks Project, whose slogan is the title of this post.

The proof invokes two different results and supposedly one can deduce the result from any of them. I am interesting on how to use the second one, [035Q](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/035Q) (3), to show the statement. The proof follows from this “because $\coprod Z_i\to X$ is integral and locally birational (as $X$ is reduced and has locally finitely many irreducible components).” If we assume $\coprod Z_i\to X$ is integral and locally birational I know how to conclude: [035Q](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/035Q), (3) gives a factorization $X^\nu\to\coprod Z_i\to X$, and $X^\nu\to\coprod Z_i$ is the normalization of $\coprod Z_i$. By taking the inverse image of each $Z_i$ in the latter morphism and applying [035K](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/035K), the result follows.

My question is: why is $\coprod Z_i\to X$ locally birational? (I know how to see that it is integral.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one hand, the morphism $\coprod Z_i\to X$ induces a bijection on irreducible components by construction. Let $Z\subset X$ be an irreducible component and let $\eta\in X$ be its generic point. Let $\mathcal{I}\subset\mathcal{O}_X$ be the ideal sheaf of sections that vanish on $Z$ (see [01J3](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01J3)). We must see that $\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}\to\mathcal{O}_{\coprod Z_i,\eta}=\mathcal{O}_{Z,\eta}=\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}/\mathcal{I}_\eta$ is an isomorphism, i.e., that $\mathcal{I}_\eta=0$. Let $U\subset X$ be a quasi-compact open neighborhood of $\eta$ (this is iff $Z$ meets $U$). Write $U=\bigcup_{\ell=1}^nU\cap Z_{i_\ell}$, where the $Z_{i_\ell}$ are the irreducible components of $X$ meeting $U$. We can suppose $Z_{i_1}=Z$. Then $F=\bigcup_{\ell=2}^n U\cap Z_{i_\ell}$ is a closed subset of $U$ and the open set $U\setminus F$ meets $U\cap Z$, i.e., $\eta\in U\setminus F$. Actually, $U\setminus F$ is a non-empty open subset contained in $U\cap Z$. Hence, $\mathcal{I}(U\setminus F)=0$, for $X$ is reduced; whence $\mathcal{I}_\eta=0$.

Comment: I've just realized that this is purely topological: Let $X$ be a topological space with locally finitely many irreducible components (by definition, each point of $X$ has a neighborhood with finitely many irreducible components). Let $Z\subset X$ be an irreducible component. There is a non-empty open set $U$ of $X$ such that $Z$ is the unique irreducible component of $X$ that $U$ meets (hence, $U\subset Z$). In a sentence: an irreducible component from a space $X$ with locally finitely many irreducible components accommodates a non-empty open subset of $X$ disjoint from the other components.